# LINQ - Nested WHERE IN query

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have the following SQL query and I want to convert it to LINQ expression.

```
SELECT `a`.*
FROM `action` AS `a`
WHERE `a`.`id` IN (
    SELECT MAX(`a1`.`id`) AS id
    FROM `action` AS `a1`
    GROUP BY `a1`.`column1`
)
```

I am able to translate inner query with LINQ expression:

```cs
IQueryable query = from a1 in db.Action
                   group a1 by new { a1.column1 } into grp_a1
                   select new
                   {
                       id = grp_a1.Max(c => c.id)
                   }
```

But how to pass the inner query as an input to the outer query?

Comment: Have you tried -> `var result = db.Action.Where(x => query.Any( q=> q.Id == x.Id));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LINQ [`.Any()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.any?view=net-6.0) to check whether `id` is in the array of nested query.

```cs
IQueryable query = from a in db.Action
                   where 
                   (
                       from a1 in db.Action
                       group a1 by new { a1.column1 } into grp_a1
                       select new
                       {
                           id = grp_a1.Max(c => c.id)
                       }
                   ).Any(x => x.id == a.id)
                   select a;
```